# Tooltip Not Showing in Custom NSTextField After Updating to macOS Sonoma

Tags: xcode, macos, tooltip, appkit, macos-sonoma

I have set tooltip properly to my custom NSTextField which is added to my custom view but it is not working now.

```
lazy var errorField: NSTextField = {
    let labelView = NSTextField()
    labelView.alignment = .right
    labelView.maximumNumberOfLines = 1
    labelView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    labelView.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail
    labelView.drawsBackground = true
    labelView.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
    labelView.textColor = NSColor.Red
    labelView.font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
    labelView.stringValue = "Error"
}()
```

in same class I have set tool tip like this:

```
errorField.toolTip = errorDetailString
```

I am facing this issue after updating my OS to Sonoma. It was working fine when i was using MacOS Ventura

[Even the in view debugging i have verfied that tool tip has been set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq0Iz.png)